# How to get Member object from user id discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to get the nickname of a user from their Id. I have the following code:

```py
id = 235088799074484224 # User Id
member2 = bot.guilds[guild_id].get_member(id)
print(member2.nick)
```

But the code gives an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vlad\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Vlad/PycharmProjects/untitled/static/bot.py", line 61, in on_message
    messages = await clean_up_messages(messages)
  File "C:/Users/Vlad/PycharmProjects/untitled/static/bot.py", line 21, in clean_up_messages
    nick = await replace_nick(i.author.id)
  File "C:/Users/Vlad/PycharmProjects/untitled/static/bot.py", line 15, in replace_nick
    return member2.display_name  # or .nick
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name'
```

The error seems to come from the fact that `member2` is always `None`. It is `None` no matter what id I use.
I have read the documentation and the `bot.guilds[guild_id]` is correct, but the `get_member()` function seems to cause the error.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Isn't it, `print(member2.nick())` (including the "()" at the end of nick). I could be wrong on this

Comment: Check if your member id and guild id are correct. [Discord Api](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) says: Returns the member or `None if not found.`

Comment: Nope, nick is a variable in the Member object

Comment: All the info is correct, the guild_id is the place of the guild in a list(the guild object is fine) and the member id is correct too

Comment: Does your bot have the needed permissions? I mean there probably is a problem that the API returns `None` at `get_member`, which only should happen if the member cannot be found...

Comment: it has Admin perms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new version of discord.py(1.5.x), there're some updates about `Intents`. Intents are like permissions, you have to define it to get channels, members(like `guild.get_member()`) and some events etc. You have to define it before defining the `client = discord.Bot(prefix='')`.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)
```

If you want to get more information about Intents, you can look at the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents).