# Send private direct message with bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm going to send someone a message from a bot, The following code snippet is what I wrote to do that when I type **`$sendpm`** it will ask for an **`id`**  and then for a **message** to send.

```
if message.content == "$sendpm":
    await message.channel.send("What is the users ID?")
    userid = await bot.wait_for('message')
    print(userid.content)
    user = bot.get_user_info(userid.content)
    await message.channel.send("What would you like to send them?")
    pm = await bot.wait_for("message")
    await user.send(user, pm.content)
```

when I do this I get this error:
**`AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_user_info'`**

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, you will not be able to use `get_user_info` in this situation. `get_user_info` also makes an API call to discord every time instead of looking in discord.py's cache, which you shouldn't do too often either. Instead, you should use [`get_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.Client.get_user) or [`get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member). Once this error is fixed, you will find that your [`await user.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user%20send#discord.User.send) line may come across an error too, which can easily be avoided by removing the first `user` argument. Remember to enable [`intents`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work) as well! Do view the revised code below.

```py
await message.channel.send("What is the users ID?")
userid = await bot.wait_for('message')

# There are two methods to get a user since get_user_info is not a good way to do it
# Method 1: Find user within the guild itself (best method)
user = message.guild.get_user(userid.content)

# Method 2: Find user through bot (can be slower if bot is in a lot of guilds)
user = bot.get_user(userid.content)

await message.channel.send("What would you like to send them?")
pm = await bot.wait_for("message")

# You do not need to have two arguments in this situation
# as you are already 'sending' to the 'user' the 'pm.content'
await user.send(pm.content)
```

[image: Code working]

**Helpful Links**:

- [How do I send a DM to anyone I want through a command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69202136/14420546) (Old + New method) - SO
- [Send DM to specific User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69931297/discord-py-send-dm-to-specific-user-id) - SO
- [How to get Member object from user id discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545638/how-to-get-member-object-from-user-id-discord-py) (INTENTS) - SO

Comment: when i change it everythingg looks to be ok and it will ask what i would like to send them and once i put the message i get this `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' ` and this refuring to the `await user.send(pm.conent)`

Comment: @Killogee I have already mentioned how to do this in my answer. Please visit this question on [How to enable member intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64832812/14420546) to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bot.get_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_user#discord.Client.get_user) method to find user by ID:

```py
await message.channel.send("What is the users ID?")
userid = await bot.wait_for('message')
print(userid.content)
user = bot.get_user(userid.content)
await message.channel.send("What would you like to send them?")
pm = await bot.wait_for("message")
await user.send(pm.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

> `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_user_info'`

[`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) has no attribute called `get_user_info`. I'm guessing you meant `get_user`/`get_member`, which returns a [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User) or [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) object which has various attributes to get the relevant "info".

```py
if message.content == "$sendpm":
        await message.channel.send("What is the users ID?")
        userid = await bot.wait_for('message')
        print(userid.content)
        user = bot.get_member(int(userid.content)) # Since message.content would always return a str, we have to make it an int in-order to get a valid "ID"
        await message.channel.send("What would you like to send them?")
        pm = await bot.wait_for("message")
        await user.send(pm.content)
```

But however, if you want `bot.get_user_info`, which could be a custom method, to be available globally(where you have access to your bot instance), you can create a 'bot variable'. Essentially a custom attribute in your bot instance.

```py
bot = commands.Bot(...)

def get_user_info(user_id: int):
    user = bot.get_member(user_id)
    return user.name, user.id

bot.get_user_info = get_user_info
```

As a sidenote: instead of checking if `message.content` is equal to a user command in an on_message event, you can start using the [`commands framework`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ext.commands)